# Как организовать хранении истории из нескольких связанны таблиц?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

```
public class Assembly
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public decimal Position {get;set;}
    public decimal Runtime {get;set;}
    public decimal Durability {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}    
}

public class AssemblyItem
{
    public int AssemblyId {get;set;}
    public int ToolId {get;set;}
    public decimal Overhang {get;set;}
    public int AmountEdges {get;set;}
    public int AmountPlates {get;set;}
}
```

Подскажите как лучше/правильней организовать хранение истории изменений, при условии что изменения возможны в обеих таблицах. Если бы изменения были в одной таблице я бы изменяемую часть вынес в отдельную таблицу и получилась связь один ко многим, а как быть когда надо сделать сохранение при изменений в двух таблицах?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26357308/6766879

Comment: Сходу гуглится, например, это готовое решение: http://entityframework-plus.net/audit

Answer (score 1):

У меня получается как то так:

```
public class Assembly
{
    public int Id {get;set}
}

public class AssemblyHistory
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime? EndDate {get;set;}
    public bool IsDeleted {get;set;}
    public decimal Position {get;set;}
    public decimal Runtime {get;set;}
    public decimal Durability {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}
}

public class AssemblyItem
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AssemblyId {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ToolId {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime? EndDate {get;set;}
    public int IsDeleted {get;set;}
    public decimal Overhang {get;set;}
    public int AmountEdges {get;set;}
    public int AmountPlates {get;set;}
}
```

Что я сделал и почему:

- `AssemblyHistory` в которой будет храниться вся история изменений.

`Assembly` нужна только для получения уникального значения для ключа(не уверен что это правильно, но как сделать иначе, пока не придумал)

- `AssemblyItem` -  добавил дополнительные поля для того что бы хранить всю историю изменений.

Answer (score 0):

Мне видится такой вариант, хотя критика, конечно, приветствуется

```
public class Assembly
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //номер версии Assembly
    public int Version { get; set; }
    //дата создания этой версии
    public DateTime VersionCreated { get; set; }

    //далее значемые свойства этой сущности...
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public class AssemblyArchive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //здесь понятно
    public int AssemblyId { get; set; }
    //номер версии Assembly
    public int AssemblyVersion { get; set; }
    //дата создания версии
    //(лучше ее все же сохранять, чтоб было проще извлекать историю версий)
    public DateTime VersionCreated { get; set; }
    //дата архивации или внесения этой версии в таблицу AssemblyArchive
    public DateTime VersionArchived { get; set; }

    //далее значемые свойства сущности Assembly...
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

Для связанной сущности *должно действовать правило*: **если создаем архивную версию основной сущности => должны сразу же создать архивную версию связанной сущности**. Аналогично правилу каскадного удаления связанных сущностей.

```
public class AssemblyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //айдишка Assembly
    public int AssemblyId { get; set; }
    //номер версии Assembly
    public int AssemblyVersion { get; set; }

    //номер версии AssemblyItem
    public int Version { get; set; }
    //дата создания этой версии AssemblyItem
    public DateTime VersionCreated { get; set; }

    //далее значемые свойства сущности AssemblyItem...
    public decimal Overhang { get; set; }
}

public class AssemblyItemArchive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //айдишка AssemblyItem
    public int AssemblyItemId { get; set; }
    //айдишка Assembly
    public int AssemblyId { get; set; }
    //номер версии Assembly
    public int AssemblyVersion { get; set; }

    //номер версии AssemblyItem
    public int Version { get; set; }
    //дата создания этой версии AssemblyItem
    public DateTime VersionCreated { get; set; }
    //дата архивации или внесения этой версии в таблицу AssemblyItemArchive
    public DateTime VersionArchived { get; set; }

    //далее значемые свойства сущности AssemblyItem...
    public decimal Overhang { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: предположим что сборка состоит из 3 элементов, то при изменении сборки я должен **продублировать** эти 3 элемента?

Comment: Да, а иначе никак не получается. Допустим у сборки была версия 2. Создаем версию 3, но айтемов, то, ссылка остается на версию 2. Можно, конечно, не делать архивную версию у айтемов, а обновить у них только соотв. ссылки на версию. Но тогда мы потеряем целостность данных, архивная версия сборки 2 останется без своих айтемов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот основные варианты.

1. При изменении дочерней сущности создавать новую версию основной сущности.

   Таблицы: Assembly -> AssemblyVerison -> AssemblyItem
2. Независимо отслеживать версии основных сущностей и дочерних.

   Таблицы: AssemblyVerison <- Assembly -> (AssemblyItem) -> AssemblyItemVerison

   Необходимость таблицы AssemblyItem зависит от того нужны ли постоянные номера дочерним сущностям

Comment: если я правильно понял, то мой ответ является интерпретацией 2 варианта, у меня могут изменится и те и другие данные, т.е. либо то либо другое, а может пройти изменение в обоих таблицах, меня только смущает отдельная таблица для служебных целей(id для составного ключа в историю)